# Jetty Error (while running Solr), without root cause

Tags: java, solr, jetty, solrj

I was working on solr and basically running some tests but somehow I am getting this exception in the logs and it is not showing any root cause.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/z9GYTRm9) is the related part of the error log. And [here](http://pastebin.com/gKGGgKZg) is my jetty.xml file.

Any one has any ideas?

EDIT: Jetty is the one that comes with default solr installation and I have only changed the configs as you can see... I get this error during stress testing and it is random.

Comment: i have put the logs and the configs... what kind of details you need?

Comment: The way you installed and setup your Jetty and whether it started failing after doing X

Comment: i have edited, @aitchnyu